# What does the error message "Column name must not be duplicated" mean in this context

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to write the values of the 4 (which i indexed with j) rows following one value within column 5 into the columns 16 to 20 (this is [j+15]. Here one dataframe (the first) of a list (SKUlist) of many data frames is addressed. Any idea what is wrong?

```
for (i in 1:length(SKUlist[[1]]) {
  for (j in 1:4) {
    SKUlist[[1]][i, j+15]=SKUlist[[1]][i+j,5]
  }
}
```

The error message is "Column name `nameofcol5` must not be duplicated".

Comment: Please edit your question if you have any additional information.

When you are appending, see what column names are being used/created.

Comment: It would be great if you could provide us with a reproducible example

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Probably your loop iteratively creates columns with the same name `"nameofcol5"` which is not allowed in R. Check a few iterations of `SKUlist[[1]][i, j+15]=SKUlist[[1]][i+j,5]` by choosing `i` and `j` manually and take measures to prevent column names to be duplicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked by at first inserting dummy columns in all of the dataframes in the list (with value 0 in each row). Thank you although.

```
for (a in 1:length(SKUlist)) {
      SKUlist[[a]]$"newcol1"=0
      SKUlist[[a]]$"newcol2"=0
      SKUlist[[a]]$"newcol3"=0
      SKUlist[[a]]$"newcol4"=0
      }
    for (a in 1:length(SKUlist)){
      for (i in 1:nrow(SKUlist[[a]])) {
        for (j in 1:4){
          SKUlist[[a]][i,j+15]=SKUlist[[a]][i+j,5]
        }
      }
    }
```